# asp.net failed to run in dot net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

The website was developed in dot net 3.5 SP1 and running ok within dot net 3.5 SP1.
But, after recompiled it into dot net 4.0 and changed the app pool to "integrated", it failed to run. The symptom is that the website was running ok for few minutes. Then, the following message will appear:

> [NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error) +197
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb) +89
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +189

If we recycle the app pool, it will work for a few minutes and then same error appear.

Any help is appreciated.

Lau.

Comment: As a first step, could you use symchk from [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) to get hold of PDBs for System.Web so you can translate the +offset into line numbers, then you can get source from the Microsoft symbol servers to see exactly what's going on on those lines. But if you're lucky someone will have seen this before?

Comment: Try the ASP.NET 4.0 application pool instead, see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Using WinDbg is the ultimate way, but be familiar with typical call stacks is much quicker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the call stack I think this exception was caused by a problematic HTTP module or handler.

You should be able to debug using Visual Studio or WinDbg.

Comment: I have a class call 'CCleanupViewStateFiles' which implemented IHttpModule. After i removed it from the web.config from "modules" section (inside System.webServer), the website looks ok now. Thanks.